# Automatically synchronise time with mac on local network without internet access

Tags: macos, timekeeping

I want my RPi to have the same time as my mac that I use to command it using SSH. The RPi and mac are connected on a local network without internet access. Currently each time the RPi restarts or shown an ssh error the time is off and I have to update it manually. How can I push the time of the mac to the rpi automatically? For example after each start-up?

Comment: You could setup a NTP server on your mac and then set the Pi to sync to your local NTP server.I am assuming that the mac has internet access, but the PI does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup a NTP server on your Mac.

In **Date & Time System Preferences** disable "**Set date & time automatically**"

edit your **/etc/ntp.conf** file to use a local (geographically) pool of servers, something like the below if you are in the US (a Google search for NTP pool server by continent should get you the correct settings for your location.):

```
server 0.us.pool.ntp.org minpoll 12 maxpoll 17
server 1.us.pool.ntp.org minpoll 12 maxpoll 17
server 2.us.pool.ntp.org minpoll 12 maxpoll 17
server 3.us.pool.ntp.org minpoll 12 maxpoll 17
```

Edit the **/etc/ntp-restrict.conf**. to allow your local network computers to sync to your NTP server. For example to allow the network 192.168.1.0/24, add:

```
restrict 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap
```

Edit the **/etc/hostconfig** and change:

```
TIMESYNC=-NO-
```

to

```
TIMESERV=-YES-
```

reboot and verify that NTP is working correctly:

```
ntpq -p
```

Next you need to modify the NTP setup on the Pi to sync to the NTP server on your mac.

> NOTE Debian Stretch by default uses `timesyncd` which is configured in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` (this normally is commented out, and NTP servers are configured at compile time).

edit the **/etc/ntp.conf** file. Find the following:

```
# You do need to talk to an NTP server or two (or three).
#server ntp.your-provider.example
```

and remove the "**#**" from the beginning of the second line, and replace the "**ntp.your-provider.example**" with your Macs name or IP Address.

Next change the following lines (note that your lines may not match exactly - server names may be different):

```
# pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will
# pick a different set every time it starts up.  Please consider joining the
# pool: <http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html>
server 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

to (add a "**#**" to the beginning of the line.):

```
# pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will
# pick a different set every time it starts up.  Please consider joining the
# pool: <http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html>
# server 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
# server 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
# server 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
# server 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

restart NTP:

```
sudo service ntp restart
```

and verify it is syncing to your mac.

References: http://blog.philippklaus.de/2012/11/setup-an-ntp-server-in-mac-os-x-10-8/
            http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-is-ntp-client-working/

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. I followed all the steps but unfortunately there time is still not syncing. There was no file /etc/hostconfig on my mac so created it with contents "TIMESERV=-YES-". Running ntpq -pn shows a table with 5 rows and thus seems to be working. I followed the steps for the RPi and ran sudo service ntp restart. Then when I type in "date" in terminal on both mac and RPi the times differ by about 1min10sec still.. I hope you can help further. Thanks!

Comment: It will take a few minutes to sync up especially if the time starts far apart as your initial question states. what happens if you type ntpq -p on the Pi? You may also want to check over these links: https://rags.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/how-to-debug-ntp-issues/ http://doc.ntp.org/3-5.93e/debug.html

Comment: wonderful, sorry I didn't understand it works in this way but you are right. Now 15min later the time is the same. Thanks again for your great help!